# Posting on wall in Android from another activity

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, post

I've an Android activity with Facebook method for logging in and **posting on wall**.
I would like to **post** from other activities once I'm logged in, so I need to reopen each time the **session**.
This is the method to post on the Facebook wall:

```
public void postOnMyWall(String streamingLink, Context mycontext) {

    context = mycontext;  
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String fbtoken = pref.getString("fbtoken", null);

    if(fbtoken != null) {

     if(!fbtoken.equals("")) {

         fbprogress = new ProgressDialog(context);

         Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

         if (session != null){

             Log.d("SOCIAL", "in posting wall, session is not null");

             // Check for publish permissions    
             List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
             if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                 //pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                 Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                         .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                 session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                 return;
             }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "name");
            postParams.putString("caption", "my caption");
            postParams.putString("description", "my desc");
            postParams.putString("link", "my link");
            postParams.putString("picture", "https://linkto/my.png");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                            .getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;

                    fbprogress.dismiss();

                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        /*
                        Log.i(activity.toString(),
                                "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    */
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        //Toast.makeText(activity
                         //       .getApplicationContext(), 
                         //       "ERROR: " + error.getErrorMessage(),
                         //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fbprogress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Errore during posting on Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                         Toast.makeText(context, "posted on Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            };

            fbprogress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            fbprogress.setIndeterminate(true);
            fbprogress.show();

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            final RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();

            Handler fb_post_handler = new Handler();
            fb_post_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  if ( task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ) {
                      task.cancel(true);
                      Toast.makeText(SocialAccess.this, "Connection timed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      fbprogress.dismiss();


                  }
              }
            }, 20000 );


        } 


         else {
             Log.d("SOCIAL", "in posting wall, session is null");
         }





        } // end  if(!fbtoken.equals("") && fbtoken != null)

    } // end token != null


        else 
        {
            Log.d("SOCIAL","not logged in fb");
            fbloginrequested = true;

        }
      }
```

From other activies, I'm calling:

SocialAccess socialogin = new SocialAccess();
socialogin.postOnMyWall(facebook_post_link, context);

The session seems to be always null if I don't reopen it each time with login.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have logged in once in your app and still your Session coming out to be null,you can try this

```
 myFbSession = Session.getActiveSession();
 if(myFbSession!=null){
   // your code here
 }else{
         myFbSession = Session
                    .openActiveSessionFromCache(context);
         if(myFbSession!=null){
          // you can call your postOnWall method again here
          }
 }
```

If above solution,doesn't works, there is a [very simple library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing) available on Github for facebook and twitter sharing that authenticates only once.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer to your specific problem, but, have you tried `Temboo`? I can't even remember the last time I had to deal with Facebook SDK implementations. In most cases is just a waste of time. With `Temboo` you can interact with all social networks by calling simple methods.